# usb key file system

Tags: usb-drive

why a usb drive can work in both linux os and windows os without the need for formating the file system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically USB drives are formatted with FAT32 or NTFS, both of which are usable in Linux.

You might also find the [Wikipedia article on USB mass storage devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class) interesting. In particular:

> The USB mass storage specification
>   does not require any particular file
>   system to be used on conforming
>   devices. Instead, it provides a simple
>   interface to read and write sectors of
>   data—much like the low-level interface
>   used to access any hard drive—using
>   the "SCSI transparent command set."
>   Operating systems may treat the USB
>   drive like a hard drive, and can
>   format it with any file system they
>   like.

Comment: NTFS usability in Linux is not always awesome. Sometimes its read only

Comment: True - in which case USB drives formatted with NTFS will be read-only on those systems.

Answer (score 0):

Because both OS'es know how to read/parse/work with the format.

Format a USB key in say OSXs HFS+ and then windows will not know which end is up (without third party drivers)